# Set ansible facts though generated name

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I’m working on a ansible playbook to deploy some configuration of services to different region, and I have initial vars imported by `include_vars` as the following:

```
common: [...]
us_local: [...]
uk_local: [...]
us_global: [...]
uk_global: [...]
```

Basically, I want to generate the configuration by including vars from `common`, all the global configs as well as the local config of that region, using `{{ site }}` variable which is defined in hosts.yaml.
For example, if the deployed host is us, then I want to use `common`, `us_local`, `us_global`, `uk_global`.

I will use a jinja2 template to generate the final config, and from my understanding, the easiest way is to create another variable called `current_site_local` and copy everything from `{{ site }}_local` into it, so that later on I could directly reference it inside the template. However, I’m having trouble making it work through `set_facts`.

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

I used the following syntax and it works:

```
- name: generate curr_site_local
  set_fact:
    current_site_local: '{{ vars[site + "_local"] }}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `combine` filter.

```
- name: Set site config '{{ site }}'
  set_fact:
    current_site_local: '{{ common 
      | combine(vars[site + "_global"])
      | combine(vars[site + "_local"]) }}'
```

In this case, the order of precedence is that the `local` config will override the `global`, and that will override the `common`.
Not sure if that is what you wanted, but that is the order you gave in your question, but the `<other>_global` is not included now.
If you want `common` to have highest precedence, just reverse the order.

See docs for [`combine`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries).

*Updated my answer with suggestion from [Matthew L Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/225016/matthew-l-daniel).*

Comment: Heh, it looks like we answered within seconds of each other, but while your answer is a lot more comprehensive than mine, I do think that having `when:` blocks isn't the correct approach to that problem. If you update your answer to use `vars` and `region`, I'll be glad to upvote yours and delete mine

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually, I just want to assign the content from {{ site }}_local, which is a list, into another variable, called current_site_local, so that later on I could use it in a template like the following:  
{% for entry in curr_site_local %}
{{ entry.name }}   xxxx    {{ entry.value }}
{% endfor %}
Tried your solution, but got an error with "ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path."

Comment: The error is just because of my typo, it works now. Thanks!